# Excel - Reverse Row of Alphanumeric Values in Different Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry everyone, not sure what I was thinking with my original question.  I messed up the rows/name/convention.

Update:  Given the following alphanumeric input within the same ROW in Excel A1:E1 (columns separated with a "|" to illustrate each column of data within Row 1):

A1:E1

Nike | Adidas | Under Armour | Champion | North Face

I'm looking to reverse the order of the row using a formula so that a formula placed within cell A2 and stepped to E2 would produce:

A2:E2

North Face | Champion | Under Armour | Adidas | Nike

While I can seem to do it with numeric characters with the following formula (reversing values in A1:E1 of 1 through 5 using) by placing formula in A2 and stepping to E2:  =INDEX($A$1:$E$1|1|COUNT(A$1:$E$1))

I cannot, however, seem to get a like formula to work with alphanumeric values.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Small trick without formulas: Create a simple helper column with numbers 1-5 and filter on this column from large to small. Delete helper column afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INDEX with some math:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,ROW(A$6)-ROW(A1))
```

[image]

Or INDEX with COUNTA (assuming no blank rows):

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,COUNTA(A1:$A$5))
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

The logic is similar for rows instead of columns:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,,COLUMN($F1)-COLUMN())
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant: that's 2 brainwaves ahead of me :) - but I get a pass since it's Friday.

Comment: A glass of beer on the right, some SO  on the left and a good series in front. Strange combination to get these brainwaves! Enjoy your friday =)

Comment: This answer works will for my previous unedited question.  Updated question to reflect correct row/column numbering where I now this this answer no longer applies.  Sorry about that.

Comment: See the edit. Can be simplified to `=INDEX(1:1,,6-COLUMN())`, similar to what @JvdV has pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if you are using Excel 2010 Professional Plus or later versions of Excel, you can use **Power Query** to transform the data in a few clicks.

Steps are:

1. Load the data to Power Query Editor;
2. Transpose the data from columns to rows;
3. Use **Reverse Rows** function to reverse the order of rows;
4. Transpose the data back from rows to columns;
5. Close and load the output to a new worksheet (by default).

> This approach is better working with a large data set. If you are only reversing one row of strings, maybe just use the formula or the trick suggested by JvdV.

Let me know if you have any questions :)